# NSString alloc initWithFormat:formatString arguments:argList crashing on 64 bit device

Tags: ios, iphone, 64-bit, iphone-6, iphone-64bit

I have a working code

```
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [arguments count]);
  void *argList = malloc(sizeof(NSObject *) * [arguments count]);
  [arguments getObjects:(id*)(const id *)argList range:range];

  //printf("hello....%lu...",sizeof(argList));
  retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString arguments:argList ];
  free(argList);`
```

it is working fine on 32 bit device,but its crashing on 64 bit devices. The only thing I can debug is that the size of argList is taking 8 byte space in 64 bit and 4 bytes in 32 bit devices.
Have anybody faced this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: That shouldn't work anywhere; that's not a `va_list`.

Comment: @Droppy this is working in my project. its an alternative for va_list ,I have checked.

Comment: @Droppy [http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html]   under "creating fake va_list"

Comment: That's from 2009, and not official.  Apple may well have changed the implementation for 64-bit or something, which they are perfectly entitled to do as `va_list` is an opaque type and off limits to us mortals.  You'll need to find another way of formatting these strings.